# Sublime Text 2: Auto complete CSS classes in HTML

Tags: html, css, sublimetext2, code-hinting

How can I have the CSS auto-complete for classes feature in Sublime Text 2?

For example, I have included a CSS file in my HTML document

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"
```

In CSS I have this:

```
.container-primary {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
        height: 115px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin: 0 -1px -1px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 800px;
}
```

How can I have the auto-complete for the CSS class when I applying the class in the HTML?

```
<div id="content" class="container-primary"></div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are asking. Are you talking about auto-completing CSS attributes and values? Or are you talking about auto-completing HTML? Or are you talking about snippets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Text 2 doesn't have support for that out of the box. [SublimeAllAutocomplete](https://github.com/alienhard/SublimeAllAutocomplete) extends the default autocomplete to find matches in all open files.

Comment: This package does work, but it has an annoying issue: it doesn't complete hyphenated CSS classes (e.g. ".menu-item").

Answer (score 1):

I already used all autocomplete in sublime but its not working well use this instead of all autocomplete its really working how you want here is link:
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CSS%20Extended%20Completions

it will awesome

Comment: This package works really well Hassan, thank you very much for this suggestion!